# Is it possible to cluster Leaflet polyline similar to markercluster in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am new to Leaflet and trying to implement Leaflet with geo map functionality. I was wondering if we can cluster the edges/polylines something similar to marker cluster.
Marker cluster groups only nodes not edges. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster.can you give some pointers please ?

Answer (score 0):

so what's the problem to start using this plugin if its functionality suits you.

Try to reformulate and provide a code example, otherwise I did not understand anything in your question...

[This plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: I am trying to implement marker cluster behaviour for leaflet Edges. By default markercluster works only with nodes . I am thinking in a way to group edges also along with nodes when user interacts with Zoom level.

Comment: @monk_7 Did you find a way to do this?